# Multiple API Calls React in Parent & Child Component

Tags: java, reactjs

I am using react for displaying User Details and Account Details

1. I have parent component
2. I have a child component

I fetch userDetails from USERAPI call and from the list I get number of accounts for the user, and for each account of the user I pass the accountID to a ACCOUNTAPI call , fetch the account details and display.

If there are more than 10 accounts for user I am getting 429 Error 'To many requests' from API , How do call API's for avoiding this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling in a free APIREST and this has a limit for your requests. Maybe.

Comment: Yes , API has a limit ,  how to control or throttle the Child Component to send only limited call initially

Comment: @NanoRV I think this should be a comment rather than a complete answer.

Comment: If you have a list with more than 10 accounts, you can paginate the list. In each page, you should have 10 accounts and when you change to another page, only maximum 10 calls to API will be sent.